# Javascript - localStorage issues

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, displaytag, remove-if

In the script below, I want to be able to display on the main html page lists of paragraphs saved in the localstorage. In the html I defined an are with the id "content". I want to display the texte stored in the localstorage in this area.

In the script below the function "displaylocalstorage" does not allow me to display the values that have been saved in the localstorage with the function "storedparagraphs". Can you please give me some guidelines to correct the "displaylocalstorage" function? Is my while loop correct ? Is the way I call the fucntion "display locastorage" is correct ?

Here is the html and js script below:

Javascript:

```
const mybutton = document.getElementById ("addbutton");
const mytext = document.getElementById("mytext");
const content = document.getElementById("content");  

function displaylocalstorage() {
let n = 0;
while (localStorage.getItem("content" + n)) {
    n++;
}
while (n){
    const paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.innerText = localStorage.getItem("content");
    content.appendChild(paragraph);
    n++
}

}

}

displaylocalstorage()
```

Comment: Start by defining n with let instead of const, since you add to it

Comment: Then have only ONE get and ONE set and store all items in an array you GET OUTSIDE the functions with JSON.parse and SET with JSON.stringify - then no need for `n` in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

displaylocalstorage is not being called.

add this to your js

```
const buttonshow = document.getElementById("buttonshow");

buttonshow.addEventListener("click", displaylocalstorage);
```

and to your html:

```
 <input
        type="button"
        value="show"
        id="buttonshow"
        class="buttonshowall"
/>
```

and console log items in the displaylocalstorage

Thank would be a good start. Other than this in that paragraph remove length from n as n is a number. If you keep it as length it will error.

```
 if(n>0){
        let lastposition = n -1;
        localStorage.removeItem("content", lastposition)
    }
```

Another big one is change const n to let as you try to update n and const won't allow you to do that.